# End of loop resistor or "terminator resistor"

Tags: resistors, wire-loop

In fire alarm control panel, I saw that at the end of the fire loop a 4.7kΩ resistor is used.

My question is why we use the value 4.7kΩ? Is their any law for this choice?

Comment: Careful with your terminology: End of Line resistors present a constant resistance so the panel can differentiate between an open or shorted line; termination resistors are used in RS-485 and similar protocols to control electrical reflections.

Comment: yes i know its purpose ,but is there a law or something for this value?

Comment: AFAIK, the value should be specified by the manufacturer of the panel/loop controller, because that's the device monitoring the current. If there is a law regarding the value, you might try checking NFPA 72.

Comment: aha okay i will see this , thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be determined by the manufacturer.  It is what the alarm system needs to see to determine that no alarm has occurred.

[Advisor Master Programming Guide](http://www.produktyutcfs.pl/files/Instrukcja_Administratora/ATSxxxxE_Instrukcja_Administratora_EN.pdf#page=79)

> **Dual zone**
>
> No: No dual zone; 4.7 kΩ resistance is a normal state; every other resistance is an alarm.